# Grouping by the inner collection element type in collection

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have

```
List<Shop> shops;

class Shop {
   private Long id;
   private String name;
   private List<Supplier> suppliers;
}

class Supplier {
   private Long id;
   private String supplierName;
}
```

What I want to get is

```
Map<Supplier, List<Shop>> supplierShopsMap;
```

How to do it with Java Streams?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should override `equal()` and `hashCode()` in `Supplier` class for grouping.

```
Map<Supplier, List<Shop>> result = shops.stream()
       .flatMap(s -> s.getSuppliers().stream()
                           .map(sup -> new SimpleEntry<>(sup, s))
       .collect(groupingBy(Entry::getKey,                 // This step requires Supplier equal function
                           mapping(Entry::getValue, toList())));
```

If you cannot modify the `Supplier` class to support `equal()` then you must create map of `Supplier`

**Edit**

As @jorn vernee pointed out, we can use `flatMap` directly without collecting into a list first. It's a huge boost

Comment: oh it's obvious I should override equals and hashcode methods of Supplier :). Thank you!

Comment: Btw, you can `flatMap` right away, you don't have to collect to a list first.